# Combining two columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to combine two columns in such a way that the second column gets added below the first column.
For eg:

```
Col 1: A B C
Col 2: D E F
```

Result :

```
Col : A B C D E F
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your description doesn't correlate with example.

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: Just combine the columns in your select statement. SELECT Col 1 + Col 2 FROM yourtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL` to get the two columns as one single column:

```
select col1 from tablename
UNION ALL
select col2 from tablename
```

If you absolutely want col1 values before col2 values, wrap it up in a derived table and add an `ORDER BY`:

```
select col from
(
    select col1 as col, 1 as ob from tablename
    UNION ALL
    select col2, 2 as ob from tablename
) dt
order by ob
```

Comment: @GiladGreen, is he really? As I understand it OP has a table with 3 rows of data, in 2 columns.

Comment: @BurhanShakir, great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2) AS col FROM table
```